# I'm trying to create a etch a sketch yet seem to get the same error in and out

Tags: python, tkinter

### the code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

global colour
global colourselection 
global count 

canvas_height = 700
canvas_width = 900
canvas_colour = "black"



p1_x = canvas_width/2
p1_y = canvas_height
line_width = 5
line_length = 5



def colour(self):
    global p1_colour
    p1_colour = 'green'
    colour = ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'grey']
    colourSelector = colour[levels]
    levels = levels + 1

def p1_move_N(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length

def p1_move_S(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y+line_length), width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_y = p1_y + line_length

def p1_move_E(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x - line_length, p1_y , width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length

def p1_move_W(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x + line_length, p1_y, width = line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_x = p1_x - line_length



#####main:
window = Tk()
window.title("Tom's")
canvas = Canvas(bg = canvas_colour, height = canvas_height, width = canvas_width, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()


window.bind("w", p1_move_N)
window.bind("s", p1_move_S)
window.bind("d", p1_move_E)
window.bind("a", p1_move_W)
window.bind("c", colour)

window.mainloop()
```

The error I seem to recieve every time is that local variable 'levels' is referenced before assignment. I am trying to make it colour change every time the key 'c' is pressed.
All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's not clear about that error? You're accessing `levels` - when you do `color[levels]` - before you define it. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You never declare levels anywhere, so the code is trying to read it when it hasn't been assigned. just make levels = 0 near the top of your code.

Comment: So I defined levels and then it came up with the error:Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "M:\year 10\computing\GCSE\sketch.py", line 32, in p1_move_N
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
  File "M:\year 10\computing\GCSE\sketch.py", line 26, in colour
    colourSelector = colour[levels]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I needed this code and was appreciative of you writing a starter script I did some small editing and fixed the problem which was not as intended in the above message but was related here is the new script if you wanna use it.

ps. it's in python just could not figure out how to post it so just copy and paste into pycharm or something and it should work just fine

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

global colour
global colourselection
global count

canvas_height = 700
canvas_width = 900
canvas_colour = "white"



p1_x = canvas_width/2
p1_y = canvas_height
line_width = 5
line_length = 5



def colour(self):
    global p1_colour, levels
    levels=0
    p1_colour = 'green'
    colour = ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'grey']
    colourSelector = colour[levels]
    levels += 1

def p1_move_N(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length

def p1_move_S(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y+line_length), width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_y = p1_y + line_length

def p1_move_E(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x - line_length, p1_y , width=line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length

def p1_move_W(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x + line_length, p1_y, width = line_width, fill=colour(self))
    p1_x = p1_x - line_length



#####main:
window = Tk()
window.title("etch a sketch")
canvas = Canvas(bg = canvas_colour, height = canvas_height, width = canvas_width, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()


window.bind("w", p1_move_N)
window.bind("s", p1_move_S)
window.bind("d", p1_move_E)
window.bind("a", p1_move_W)
window.bind("c", colour)

window.mainloop()
```